# WaitForControlEnabled() performance

Tags: javascript, html, coded-ui-tests

We've some JS on our web page which enables a UI control (HTML input element).

Our think time is 0, therefore we have to add some deterministic wait before Coded UI test is allowed to click on the UI control. We used `UITestControl.WaitForControlEnabled`, however, observed weird behavior:

- It takes around a minute to determine that the control has been enabled, however, the JS takes not even a second
- It is possible to specify a timeout using the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee379417.aspx overload, this works perfectly - however, only if the element has already been enabled within the timeout span

What is the recommended way to use WaitForControlEnabled, it should return as soon as the control is enabled and not wait forever or require us to specify a timeout...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the bool return value from WaitForControlEnabled lets you know if the control has become enabled within the timeout period? In which case you can do:

```
while (!myUiElement.WaitForControlEnabled(SOME_TIMEOUT_VALUE)) { }
// You should now be able to interact with the control
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
control.WaitForControlReady()
```

before performing any action on control. It will wait till your control becomes ready to accept any action.